# Did "errand boys" really have to wear handcuffs attached to the briefcase?

Tags: united-states, 1950s

In a Donald Duck comic published in 1994 (possibly conceived up to a few years prior, and possibly "set" in the 1950s), Donald Duck is forced to become an errand boy. The boss gives him a briefcase with handcuffs attached to the handle and locks the other end to the wrist of Donald. Supposedly, the purpose is for it to not get lost/stolen on the way to the customer. (Although it's not explained at all in the comic.)

1. Was (or *is*) this actually done in real life? Nothing about the episode suggests that this is made-up for the Duck universe; it's handled at something obvious and "everyday".
2. If this was real, how did they actually deliver the briefcase to the customer once they arrived at the destination? Donald did not get any key to the handcuffs, and if he had been given them, the point of attaching him to the briefcase would be lost.

It seems like a feasible security measure to me, but I don't understand the practicality of separately delivering the key. (If that was done.)

Comment: Welcome to History.SE [USERNAME]! Could you [edit] your question to clarify where you've searched and what you found already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the Wikipedia entry on the topic, if one exists. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour] and [help] and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: [handcuff briefcase straight dope](https://boards.straightdope.com/t/the-handcuffed-briefcase-trope/649856) [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/2s8fzv/redditors_who_have_ever_needed_to_handcuff_a/) [Smithsonian](https://www.businessinsider.com/mysterious-black-briefcase-follows-us-president-2015-2)  (The Smithsonian link and the discussion of Operation Mincemeat are probably the best references)

Comment: Handcuff keys are not unique to a particular set of cuffs...

Comment: @DJohnM: That is an implementation detail, for the convenience of cops.  If you were using a briefcase that was lockable to a courier's wrist, you would of course use a different method, with keys (or combinations) held by the sender & receiver.  (As a practical matter, when I used to travel for work, I would regularly lock my laptop to a bracket in my car, so it's not inherently impractical.)